# Live monitoring an outbound call using twiml

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am placing outbound calls using the TwiML voice API.

My goal is to place an outbound call and be able to listen to call the call live so that the call can be monitored live instead of only being able to listen to a recording afterward.

Currently, I am using the `<Stream>` verb to listen to one side of the conversation, however, the stream only includes the audio from the party being called and not the audio that Twilio is sending (for example the audio from a `<Say>` verb is omitted).

Is there a way to get both sides of the conversation live? One thought I had was adding another Twilio number to the call and listening to the stream from that number, but that felt clumsy.

Any help/direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at using the `Participants` resource and adding yourself as a coach? https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Stream` verb has a `track` attribute that specifies which side of the call to stream: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream#attributes-track.

I had some issues trying to convert the `both_tracks` stream to a pcm stream, so instead, I created two streams for each side of the call which worked well.

Comment: How did you create two streams using TwiML?

Comment: In the twiml when you make the call you can do this:
```
<Response>
    <Start>
        <Stream name="Example Audio Stream" url="wss://mystream.ngrok.io/audiostream" />
    </Start>
    <Start>
        <Stream name="Example Audio Stream 2" url="wss://mystream.ngrok.io/audiostream2" />
    </Start>
</Response>
```
This will start two streams of the call to both of the specified endpoints.